# How can I write to a text file

Tags: android, sd-card

I got reading from a text file line by line working - but I need to write to a text file.  I need to write over it really but whatever I try it doesn't seem to work.

I have an existing text file with the value "board1" in it and I need to change that on a button click to board10.

Here is what I'm trying at the moment.

```
String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();


try {
    FileWriter filenew = new FileWriter(sdcard + "/multi10/default.cfg");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(filenew);
    bw.write("board12");
    bw.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```

if someone could help me I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: What are you seeing that makes you think that it is not working? Are you getting exceptions? Catching an exception without doing anything is bad. You should do what your comment says.  Do you have permissions in your app for writing to external storage?

Comment: Should you add "bw.flush()" before "bw.close()"?

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying nothing is being written to the file, where would I see any errors would that be in logcat?

Comment: Anything that is logged goes to logcat. You are not logging anything though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the little description you have given , I would say, Check the permission in AndroidManifest file for this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I can't believe I did this!  I thought this was set noob mistake - thank you!

Comment: The importance of this is that , the permissions will be displayed to the user when they install your app. So if your app really needs to write to external dir , use it. In your case its required.